# How to avoid static_cast in Pub/Sub system? (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, events, event-handling, publish-subscribe

I'm designing a simple Pub/Sub system (based on Boost Signals2). In this system, you can subscribe, via `EventManager::subscribe`, to specific types of events. It's frustrating, however, for each subscriber to have to cast `const Event&` to the specific event which they have subscribed to. What's a good/ elegant way to avoid this problem? I'm happy to switch to a very different design.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class Event {
  virtual std::string get_type() = 0;
};

class EventA : public Event {
  std::string get_type() override {
    return "EVENT_A";
  }
  int get_foo() {
    return 5;
  }
};

class EventManager {
 public:
  void publish_event(const Event &e);
  void subscribe(std::string type, std::function<void(const Event &)> subscriber);
};

int main() {
  EventManager event_manager;
  event_manager.subscribe("EVENT_A", [&](const Event &e) {
    const EventA &event_a = static_cast<const EventA &>(e); // how can avoid cast here?
    // do stuff with event_a
  });

  EventA event_a;
  event_manager.publish_event(event_a);
}
```

Comment: From the limited information you have described, it's hard to tell. If your "subscriber" function only uses functions provided by `Event`, then there is no need for a static cast e.g. `Event` provides the function `get_foo()` and (if it is `virtual`) `EventA` overrides it.   If you want `EventA` to have functions that are not known to `Event` - and for your "subscriber" to call them directly - then you need the `static_cast`.  Depending on your needs, you might want to look up techniques to separate objects from algorithms - such as the visitor design pattern, or "double dispatch" techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is typical bottle-neck pattern where you have polymorphism that does not suit your needs. It makes you to squeeze different data through same hole and later to figure what it is. So you have to subscribe to some kind of string name to "base" event like such:

```
void subscribe(std::string type, std::function<void(const Event &)> subscriber);
```

What you might want is to subscribe to specific events with handlers of specific types:

```
void subscribe(std::function<void(const SquareEvent &)> subscriber); 
void subscribe(std::function<void(const RoundEvent &)> subscriber);
```

Or maybe you even want to have generic subscription for that as:

```
template<class E>
void subscribe(std::function<void(const E &)> subscriber) {
     // implement 
}
```

Latter has to have its implementation in header. If you do it like that then you do not need to cast the `EventA&` to `Event&` and then in handler `Event&` back to `EventA&`.